# Supabase onAuthStateChange with React.useEffect lost session on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase

I am using the React.useEffect for detecting the Auth State change in Supabase Authentication.
My problem is to simply keep track of the session even if page refreshes. I tried following code but the session variable become null everytime I refresh the page. If I switch some tab on my browser or change the focus of the page then the session is retrieved.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./componenets/Home";
import NoPage from "./componenets/NoPage";
import Layout from "./componenets/Layout";
import Contact from "./componenets/Contact";
import Login from "./componenets/Login";
import PrivateRoutes from "./utils/PrivateRoutes";
import Products from "./pages/Products";
import { supabase } from "./libs/supabase";
import { Auth, ThemeSupa } from "@supabase/auth-ui-react";

import React from "react";
import Landing from "./componenets/Landing";

function App() {
  const [session, setSession] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const { data: authListener } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(
      (event, _session) => {
        console.log(`Supbase auth event: ${event}`);
        setSession(_session);
      }
    );
    return () => {
      authListener.subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route
          path="log2"
          element={
            <Auth
              supabaseClient={supabase}
              appearance={{ theme: ThemeSupa }}
              providers={["google", "facebook", "twitter"]}
            />
          }
        />

        <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Home />} />
          <Route element={<Products />} path="/products" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout session={session} />}>
          <Route index element={<Landing />} />
          <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The state will always reset on page reload. You need to store in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Comment: doesn't useEffect supposed to fire if the value changes? but it only fires the on browser tabs change? I also want to understand if I am doing something wrong with the useEffect hook? I am totally new to this.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in comment, useEffect will get triggered on every change (depends on what you want it to listen). In your case, you have 0 dependency so it will get fired only once per page load.

Here is how I would deal with your session :

```
function App() {
  const [session, setSession] = React.useState(
    sessionStorage.getItem("session")
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify(session));
  }, [session]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const { data: authListener } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(
      (event, _session) => {
        console.log(`Supbase auth event: ${event}`);
        setSession(_session);
      }
    );
    return () => {
      authListener.subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [session]);
```

With `session` in useEffect dependencies, on each session change, the useEffect will get triggered. And the sessionStorage will allow you to retrieve session data

Comment: Thanks. It really helps me understand this situation. But doesn't I need to JSON.parse in case of fetching from sessionStorage?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the value stored is already an object or array, you don't need. You can handle it as you want